# Why does JavaScript on my website only work after I refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**EDIT:** I noticed that the issue is non-existent if I run my project locally (using Brackets live preview). The issue only occurs when I deploy the website to getforge.io.

I have a multi-page website using HTML/CSS/Bootstrap/JS. Whenever I navigate to another page, the dropdown  menu on my navbar doesn't work (I can open the navbar, but the "About" dropdown doesn't work unless I refresh the page). I also have sliding panels on another page that has the same issue, only works if I refresh after the page load. I tried adding data-ajax="false" to my anchors, but that didn't work. Here is some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/queries.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
    family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <title>Level Red Boxing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="landingHeader">

        <nav>
            <div id="top" class="row">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="resources/css/img/brand2.png" 
    class="logo"></a>
                <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
                    <li><a id="workout" href="theworkout.html">The Workout</a>
    </li>
                    <li><a href="motivators.html">Trainers</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-
    toggle="dropdown" href="#">About<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="thelevels.html">The Levels</a></li>
                            <li><a href="sixpunches.html">Learn the Moves</a>
    </li>
                            <li><a href="philosophy.html">Philosophy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="press.html">Press</a></li>
                            <li><a href="privateevents.html">Private Events</a>
    </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="buyclasses.html">Buy Classes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="accountButton">My 
    Account</a></li>

                </ul>
                <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-
    round"></i></a>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/selectivizr/1.0.3b/selectivizr.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>

    </body>
```

And here is the function for sliding panels:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".flip").click(function () {
    $('.panel').not($(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow")).slideUp("slow");  
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you include the scripts needed for the dropdown on the pages you navigate to?

Comment: Have you seen any error in console?

Comment: Have you included script to other pages? Or is it so that you have to realod other pages for it to work?

Comment: @Strernd Please see my edit. Everything works perfect locally, but the live site hosted by getforge.io is where the issue occurs...

Comment: @margarita There are no errors. What script are you referring? Also, please see my edit. Everything runs perfect locally, but when I push to getforge.io and test the live site, it stops working and I have to refresh the page for javascript to work.

Comment: Do you have a live link?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by disabling TurboJS in the settings on getforge.io.

Answer (score 0):

Remove All your script out side of body

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/queries.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
    family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <title>Level Red Boxing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="landingHeader">

        <nav>
            <div id="top" class="row">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="resources/css/img/brand2.png" 
    class="logo"></a>
                <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
                    <li><a id="workout" href="theworkout.html">The Workout</a>
    </li>
                    <li><a href="motivators.html">Trainers</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-
    toggle="dropdown" href="#">About<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="thelevels.html">The Levels</a></li>
                            <li><a href="sixpunches.html">Learn the Moves</a>
    </li>
                            <li><a href="philosophy.html">Philosophy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="press.html">Press</a></li>
                            <li><a href="privateevents.html">Private Events</a>
    </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="buyclasses.html">Buy Classes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="accountButton">My 
    Account</a></li>

                </ul>
                <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-
    round"></i></a>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>


    </body> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/selectivizr/1.0.3b/selectivizr.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Outside of body? What will this change?